Преобразование координат из неизвестной проекции в WGS
От сайта с геоданными получаю pbf tile с geojson. Однако координаты в этом geojson в неизвестном мне формате.
Хочу узнать, можно ли в общем случае имея несколько соответствий x,y -> x1, y1 определить функцию для преобразования из заданной системы координат в целевую (WGS84). Желателен код на python. Но в целом достаточно псевдокода.
Пример координат. Лежат в Краснодарском крае.
 {"geometry": {"type": "Point", "coordinates": [11682, 46731]}

